# Waiting for a page to load with Selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

How would I select a value in a data-bind span so that I can use Selenium's wait command to wait for it to appear?

I want it to wait until the firstNum span appears.

```
<div class ="pagination-info">
     <span class="visiblelist">Showing</span>
     <span data-bind="number: firstNum">100</span>
     <span data-bind="number: lastNum">130</span>
</div>
```

Code snippet:

```
DRIVER = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
DRIVER.get(url)
# wait should go here
data = DRIVER.page_source
```

P.s. It's a dynamic site, so I'll be on url&page=1 and go to url&page=2 and I'll need to wait for the dynamic element to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait for the visibility of the `<span>` element with a *data-bind* value you can use the following block of code :

```
DRIVER = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
DRIVER.get(url)
WebDriverWait(DRIVER, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pagination-info']//span[@data-bind='number: firstNum' and contains(.,'100')]"))) 
data = DRIVER.page_source
```

Comment: The span with the data-bind value exists on all pages, so I need to check for the correct value (e.g. 100 in the example) to appear.

Comment: I'm also iterating over many pages, so the number will be changing, so I'm doing: `path = "//div[@class='pagination-info']//span[@data-bind='number: firstNum' and contains(.,'" + start_num + "')]"`. and then `WebDriverWait(DRIVER, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path)))`. But I'm getting an error on the number of arguments (3 instead of 2). There must be a stupid typo I'm missing.

Comment: I found it, I missed an ending parenthesis at the end. It works perfectly, thanks.